# how set java frame's side area unable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

my project contains frame A and frame B , frame A contains a jtable , when opening the frame B , we'll work with data selected in jtable of frame A  ... So how can i make user  works just with frame B and can't do anythings outside ,until frame B be  closed ?!
thanks!

Comment: Make frame B a modal JDialog.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Done ! .. thank u very much